# How to solve this specific .xlsx to .xml transformation case?

Tags: excel, xml, vba, xslt, transformation

I have a large Excel file (.xlsx), with the following columns and some example content:

[image: xlsx-example]

The file is very large with 981 rows.

Now I want **every** row to be written in a separate XML file, which should follow a specific "template", that I determine. It would be the following one (no need to read it all :) )

Now I need some code, that allows me to say

- For each row in the .xlsx file, generate a new XML file using the template above
- The content in column `Nummer/Kunde/Titel/Datum/System/hh:mm:ss` should be automatically written in the following XML tags [...]
- The special thing is that as you can see in my template, most of the XML tags are already filled out.

But it does not work properly if you have a template. The first lines of this code describe the XML tags. I just can't describe *all* my tags like this and I don't know how to tell that most tags are already filled.

I have some light experience with XSLT and I have a feeling that this task could be done with it, I just don't know how.

Does anyone have some ideas? Thank you all in advance! :)

Comment: Is the solution as simple as using [load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762722%28v%3dvs.85%29) (which loads an XML document from a file) instead of using [loadXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms754585(v=vs.85)) (which loads an XML document from a string)?

Comment: i tried to add the line 
doc.Load ("//test.xml")

(not the real path, just modified it for data protection)
instead of the LoadXML-line

after that i reach an Error '91'

Comment: my test.xml does look like this
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<name>
</name>
<birthday>
</birthday>
<amount>
</amount>

Comment: Where in your posted template should Excel data be mapped to? Your post omits the tags: *The content in column Nummer/Kunde/Titel/Datum/System/hh:mm:ss should be automatically written in the following XML tags [...]*. I cannot read the language to even assume.

Comment: Since this is not for sure (the reason i wasn't that specific), one can assume the example file test.xml in my own answer to this topic.

The main problem is to get it done, no matter for which tag. 

Isn't it possible to abstract the problem a little and focus on the workflow?

Sorry for my bad english, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Consider a parameterized XSLT where you iterate through the rows of your Excel file and pass them as parameters from VBA to XSLT. Windows' MSXML library supports this method via a [processor object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms753809(v%3Dvs.85)).

**Input XML** *(example "template")*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <nummer></nummer>
    <kunde></kunde>
    <titel></titel>
    <datum></datum>
    <system></system>
    <dauer></dauer>
</root>
```

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:param name="nummer" />
    <xsl:param name="kunde" />
    <xsl:param name="titel" />
    <xsl:param name="datum" />
    <xsl:param name="system" />
    <xsl:param name="dauer" />

    <!-- IDENTITY TRANFORM -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <nummer><xsl:value-of select="$nummer"/></nummer>
            <kunde><xsl:value-of select="$kunde"/></kunde>
            <titel><xsl:value-of select="$titel"/></titel>
            <datum><xsl:value-of select="$datum"/></datum>
            <system><xsl:value-of select="$system"/></system>
            <dauer><xsl:value-of select="$dauer"/></dauer>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**VBA** *(parameter names must match to above XSLT)*

```vb
Sub Param_XSLT_Process()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    ' ADD REFERENCE Microsoft XML, v6.0
    Dim xmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xslDoc As New MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument60
    Dim xslTemp As New MSXML2.XSLTemplate60
    Dim xslProc As Object

    Dim lLastRow As Long, lRow As Long

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
    xmldoc.async = False
    xmldoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Input.xml"

    xslDoc.async = False
    xslDoc.setProperty "AllowDocumentFunction", True
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLT\Script.xsl"

    ' INITIALIZE NEEDED OBJECTS
    Set xslTemp.stylesheet = xslDoc
    Set xslProc = xslTemp.createProcessor()

    xslProc.input = xmldoc

    ' ITERATE THROUGH EACH ROW, TRANSFORM, SAVE XML OUTPUT
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
       lLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

       For lRow = 2 To lLastRow
           xslProc.addParameter "kunde", CStr(.Cells(lRow, 1).Value)    ' ADD PARAMETER(S)
           xslProc.addParameter "nummer", CStr(.Cells(lRow, 2).Value)
           xslProc.addParameter "dauer", CStr(.Cells(lRow, 3).Value)
           xslProc.addParameter "titel", CStr(.Cells(lRow, 4).Value)
           xslProc.addParameter "system", CStr(.Cells(lRow, 5).Value)
           xslProc.addParameter "datum", CStr(.Cells(lRow, 6).Value)

           xslProc.transform                                            ' TRANSFORM XML
           newDoc.LoadXML xslProc.output                                ' LOAD RESULT TREE
           newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\Output_" & lRow - 1 & ".xml"         ' SAVE OUTPUT TO FILE
       Next lRow
    End With

    MsgBox "Successfully processed XML files!", vbInformation

ExitHandle:
    Set xmldoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing
    Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set xslTemp = Nothing: Set xslProc = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Err.Raise xslDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , xslDoc.parseError.reason
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub
```

---

**Actual XML**

Consider this XSLT for your actual which adjusts the first 6 attribute/item nodes under `<category name="Archivalie_Categories_Attributes:Archivalie">` and keeps everything else the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:param name="nummer" />
    <xsl:param name="kunde" />
    <xsl:param name="titel" />
    <xsl:param name="datum" />
    <xsl:param name="system" />
    <xsl:param name="dauer" />

    <!-- IDENTITY TRANFORM -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="category[@name='Archivalie_Categories_Attributes:Archivalie']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <attribute dateformat="" name="Mandant">
                <item><xsl:value-of select="$nummer"/></item>
            </attribute>
            <attribute dateformat="" name="Bemerkungen zur Stufe">
                <item><xsl:value-of select="$kunde"/></item>
            </attribute>
            <attribute dateformat="" name="Signatur">
                <item><xsl:value-of select="$titel"/></item>
            </attribute>
            <attribute dateformat="" name="Titel">
                <item><xsl:value-of select="$datum"/></item>
            </attribute>
            <attribute dateformat="" name="Bemerkungen">
                <item><xsl:value-of select="$system"/></item>
            </attribute>
            <attribute dateformat="" name="Versicherungswert">
                <item><xsl:value-of select="$dauer"/></item>
            </attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute[position() &gt; 6]|set"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooo much! Worked fine with my example-data. Try it on monday again, and will inform you if everything worked!

Comment: Oh, there's one question already:

Assumed, that my Input-XML is the complicated one in my first post (the one starting with the <archivaliedata>-tag). How should my XSLT-File look like, if i want to fill my parameters in tags of this Input XML-File? I'm asking, because at this point i can not "hardcode" the tags around the <xsl:value-of>-instructions as it is at the moment. i hope you understand what I'm trying to say. Would be the best if you can give me another example with the orgin XML-Input-file, the exact tags for mapping can be random, it should just use the origin XML-Input-file

Comment: See extended answer where you will have to adjust the XSLT template match to the exact node(s) you want to pass parameters and add the identity transform.

Comment: Ok, there's another error i can't handle. I copy my files in here as a new answer...

Comment: here is the new thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389544/how-to-fix-the-stylesheet-does-not-contain-a-document-element-the-stylesheet-m/57391551#57391551